# Putting values into dynamically generated input types with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have Range/Number type inputs that are synchronized and dynamically generate input fields as much as their values.

Then I have a button that will fill the generated input fields with an arbitrary value.

The dynamically generated input fields each have unique IDs, but the `document.getElementById()` function fails to find any of the IDs and returns null.

Is there a way to change the value of the generated fields within the `randomizeItemTypes()` function?

```
function randomizeItemTypes(textbox) {
  var rackNum = textbox.replace("itemSlider", "").replace("numOfTypes", "");
  var numOfTypes = document.getElementById("numOfTypes1").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfTypes; i++) {
    document.getElementById("rack" + rackNum + "." + i).value = 4;
  }
}
```

The following link is the CodePen to my code:
http://codepen.io/cnc4ever/pen/LGNMEp

Thanks guys!

Comment: fyi, having dots in an ID is not a good idea. at some point you'll probably use selectors to match elements (e.g. jquery or `document.querySelector`) and then you'd need to escape those dots

Comment: Try this; function randomizeItemTypes(textbox) {
      var rackNum = textbox.replace("randomize1", "1");
      var numOfTypes = document.getElementById("numOfTypes1").value;
      for (var i = 0; i < numOfTypes; i++) {
        document.getElementById("rack" + rackNum + "." + i).value = 4;
      }
    }

Comment: wow wow wow...I do not believe what I just did..
what a dumb mistake.
I'm new to HTML so I just assumed that dynamically generated objects worked differently, my bad! thanks for pointing it out!
I'll take note of having dots in the ID too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rackNum` is giving some string instead of numbers
Your id for textbox is something like `rack1.0 , rack1.1` 
use `document.getElementById("rack1" + "." + i).value = 4;` instead

Comment: I realised it was such a noob mistake..thanks for pointing it out! totally my bad..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
   <body>
 <div class="itemsTypes1">
    <input id="itemSlider1" type="range" value="" min="1" max="10" step="1" onchange="printValue(this.value);drawItemTypes('itemSlider1');" />

     <input id="numOfTypes1" type="number" value="" min="1" max="10" onchange="printValue(this.value);drawItemTypes('numOfTypes1');" />
    <p id="itemTypes1Area"></p>
  <button id="randomize1" onclick="randomizeItemTypes()">Randomize</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
         function printValue(data) {

              var x = document.getElementById("itemSlider1").value = data;
              var y = document.getElementById("numOfTypes1").value = data;

            }
         function randomizeItemTypes() {
              var randomValue= Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
              printValue(randomValue);
            }
      </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do not need to create so many function to achieve simple things . please let me know if this is use full for you.

Comment: My emphasis was on inserting the value to the input fields, but it was just a simple error on my part. Thanks anyway!

Comment: is my code is doing what you wants to achieve through your code.?

Comment: The randomize part yes, but I created other functions to have more input fields. Try changing the value of the first input field.